# Can't open software-center ( No module named gi.repository ) + yum ( no module named yum ), ( ubuntu )

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, yum, pyenv

My OS is ubuntu 15.10 in VirtualBox , I found I can't upgrade my OS and can't open the software-center.
I have tried to google this problem, but when I found some ways I can try.. I would find more new problems too. And can't solve those problems.

I try to describe in detail what things I have done and the condition (error messages) of computer.. Thanks!

**$ software-center**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 25, in <module>
    from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject
ImportError: No module named gi.repository
```

I google "No module named gi.repository" and found that I need to install PyGObject , but..

**$ sudo pip install PyGObject**

```
Collecting PyGObject
  Downloading pygobject-2.28.3.tar.bz2 (889kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 890kB 917kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGObject using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGObject in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gaC6QU/PyGObject/
```

---

- I follow the [[SOLVED]No module named gi.repository. How do I get it?](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=204849)

**$ which python**   ( can I / should I modify it to `/usr/bin/python` ?)

```
/home/thisray/.pyenv/shims/python
```

**$ pacman -Qikk python-gobject python**

```
XIO:  fatal IO error 22 (Invalid argument) on X server ":0"
      after 4155 requests (4155 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

**$ python -c "import gi; print(gi.__spec__)"**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gi
```

**$ python -c "import gi; print(gi.__dict__)"**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gi
```

---

- the problem about `yum`

**$ sudo apt-get install yum**

```
yum is the newest version  ( in Taiwanese )
```

**$ yum --version**

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   No module named yum

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.7.11 (default, Apr 25 2016, 16:08:52) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010]

If you cannot solve this problem yourself, please go to 
the yum faq at:
  http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq
```

**$ whereis python**

```
python: /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.4m 
/usr/bin/python2.7-dbg /usr/bin/python3.4 
/usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python3.5m 
/usr/bin/python2.7-dbg-config /usr/bin/python 
/usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/lib/python3.4 
/usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.5 
/etc/python3.4 /etc/python2.7 /etc/python /etc/python3.5 
/usr/local/bin/python2.7-config /usr/local/bin/python2.7 
/usr/local/lib/python3.4 /usr/local/lib/python2.7 
/usr/local/lib/python3.5 /usr/include/python3.4m 
/usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.5m 
/usr/include/python2.7_d /usr/share/python 
/home/thisray/.pyenv/shims/python3.5m-config 
/home/thisray/.pyenv/shims/python2.7-config 
/home/thisray/.pyenv/shims/python2.7 
/home/thisray/.pyenv/shims/python3.5-config 
/home/thisray/.pyenv/shims/python3.5m 
/home/thisray/.pyenv/shims/python 
/home/thisray/.pyenv/shims/python3.5 
/home/thisray/bin/python2.7 
/home/thisray/bin/python /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

And I tried `$ sudo vi /usr/bin/yum` and modify the `#!/usr/bin/python` to each path in `$ whereis python` , and use different versions of Python to do  `>> import yum` , but the `yum` still don't work

---

- I have installed `pyenv` , and have tried there three versions to test `yum`

**$ pyenv versions**

```
* system (set by /home/thisray/.pyenv/version)
  2.7.11
  3.5.1
```

( I usually use `$ pyenv global 2.7.11` )

**$ pip --version**

```
pip 8.1.1 from /home/thisray/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

**$ pip list**

```
pip (8.1.1)
setuptools (20.10.1)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

**$ /usr/bin/python2.7-dbg**

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yum
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/yum/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import rpm
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpm/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from rpm._rpm import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rpm/_rpm.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: Py_InitModule4_64
[52069 refs]
```

---

I think the source of all problems is from that I install many different versions of Python, and I did't use the well way to install/upgrade them....

This is my first time to ask question here and in English. I hope you can understand what I mean and what my problem is. Thanks a lot and sorry about my English, I have tried to solve it all day long... if the problem can be solved, I would very appreciate!

If there is anything need to be test or explained more, Please tell me, Thanks !!

Comment: You are correct that your problems probably all stem from replacing the system Python.  In general, you should not mix packages using `apt-get` with packages installed using `pip install`, because the two systems have different mechanisms for managing software dependencies, and `pip installing` something into the system Python may break your system.  Your best recovery option at this point is probably to re-install from scratch.  Also, Ubuntu does not use `yum` and it's not clear why you're trying to use that (`yum` is used on CentOS/Fedora/Red Hat).